# @Transactional multiple update; commit every single query

Tags: java, spring, commit, transactional

I have 2 methods in my service

```
public void updateAll() {
   long[] ids = new long[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
   for (long id : ids) {
        updateId(id);
    }
}

public updateId(long id) {
  repository.update(id);
}
```

Let's assume that after the 5th update I have an exception, I would like that the first 4 operations would be committed anyway.

I'm using the @Transactional annotation but if I put the annotation in both methods it doesn't work.

Do I need other parameter?? It might be propagation??

Could you show me how to set this methods?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just have:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public updateId(long id) {
}
```

But, the important bit, call that method from another class.
i.e. move your loop out of this class.

The transactional annotations only kick-in when that public method is called from the outside.  Within the same class, calling one transactional method from another will still only use the transaction of the first method.

Answer (score 1):

You need a separate `@Transactional` on `updateId` with `REQUIRES_NEW`.

Comment: so it should be:
'@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void updateAll() {...   }
}
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public updateId(long id) {..}
'

Comment: @pacio14 yes, looks like it. Just make sure you are calling the second method *from another bean*